# Datatables editer not pass to controller after changes

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I use data tables editor for edit specific column. after update row that whole data pass to the controller when I click on the button which is not in a table.

here is my code of view

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ToJavaScriptDate(value) {
            var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
            var results = pattern.exec(value);
            var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
            return (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {

            editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
                table: "#example",
                idSrc: 'ID',
                fields: [{
                    label: "PQTY:",
                    name: "PQTY"
                }, {
                    label: "PRCNO:",
                    name: "PRCNO"
                }, {
                    label: "PRCReadyDT:",
                    name: "PRCReadyDT",
                    type: 'datetime',
                    def: function () { return new Date(); },
                    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                    fieldInfo: 'US style m-d-y date input with 12 hour clock',
                    opts: {
                        minutesIncrement: 5
                    }
                }, {
                    label: "REMARKS:",
                    name: "REMARKS"
                }
                ]
            });
            $('#example').on('click', 'tbody td.editable', function (e) {
                //editor.inline(this);
                editor.inline(this, {
                    buttons: '_basic'
                });
            });
            $('#OrderNo').on("change", function () {
                $('#example').DataTable().destroy();
                $('#tblbody').empty();
                var code = $("#OrderNo").children("option:selected").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetPRCDataFromOrderNo", "PRC")',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ 'oano': code }),
                    success: function (list) {
                        if (Object.keys(list).length > 0) {
                            $('#tblbody').text("");
                            BindData(list);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#tblbody').text("");
                            var text = "No Data found.";
                            $('#tblbody').append(
                                '<tr class="odd"><td valign="top" colspan="20" class="dataTables_empty">'
                                + text + '</td></tr>');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () { alert('Error. Please try again.'); }
                });
            });
            var BindData = function (response) {
                var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    data: response,
                    responsive: true,
                    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                    "lengthMenu": [
                      [10, 25, 50, -1],
                      [10, 25, 50, "All"]
                    ],
                    columns: [
                        {
                            data: null,
                            defaultContent: '',
                            className: 'select-checkbox',
                            orderable: false
                        },
                         { data: 'PRCReadyDT', className: 'editable' },
                         { data: 'PRCNO', className: 'editable' },
                         { data: 'REMARKS', className: 'editable' },
                         { data: 'OANO' },
                         { data: 'ID' },
                         { data: 'PONO' },
                         { data: 'POLI' },
                         { data: 'MOULDCODE' },
                         { data: 'DESCRIPTION' },
                         { data: 'Drg' },
                         { data: 'Rev' },
                         { data: 'METALCODE' },
                         { data: 'METALNAME' },
                         { data: 'WEIGHT' },
                         { data: 'QTY' },
                         { data: 'PRC' },
                         { data: 'DELIVERYDT' },
                         { data: 'PQTY', className: 'editable' },
                         { data: 'Machining' }
                    ],
                    language: {
                        search: "_INPUT_",
                        searchPlaceholder: "Search records",
                    },
                    select: {
                        style: 'os',
                        selector: 'td:first-child'
                    },
                    buttons: [
                        { extend: "edit", editor: editor }
                    ]
                });
            }
            var table = $('#example').DataTable();
            $('#save').click(function () {
                debugger;
                var data = table.$('#tblbody').serialize();
                alert(
                    "The following data would have been submitted to the server: \n\n" +
                    data+ '...'
                );
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("PRCGenerate", "PRC")',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#modelBody2").html(data);
                        $("#model2").modal("show");
                    },
                    //error: function () { alert('Error. Please try again.'); }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header card-header-primary card-header-icon">
        <div class="card-icon">
            <i class="material-icons">sort</i>
        </div>
        <h4 class="card-title">Filter</h4>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top:15px;">
                <p>
                    @Html.DropDownList("OrderNo", Session["ono"] as SelectList, "-- Select Orderno-- ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "selectpicker", data_style = "select-with-transition" })
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header card-header-primary card-header-icon">
        <div class="card-icon">
            <i class="material-icons">assignment</i>
        </div>
        <h4 class="card-title">PRC Details</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="material-datatables">
            <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover nowrap text-center" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:1px !important;"></th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PRCReadyDT)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PRCNO)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.REMARKS)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OANO)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PONO)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.POLI)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MOULDCODE)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DESCRIPTION)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Drg)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rev)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.METALCODE)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.METALNAME)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WEIGHT)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.QTY)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PRC)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DELIVERYDT)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PQTY)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Machining)
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tblbody">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-finish btn-fill btn-rose btn-wd" name="Save" value="Generate" id="save" style="float:right;" />
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my controller for getting a record

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PRCGenerate(List<sp_PRC_Record_Result> PRC)
    {
        string elementId = this.HttpContext.Request.Form["OANO"];
        return View();
    }
```

Here is my output:

[Output Image with datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rEb3.png)

When clicking on Generate button the whole datatable value send to the controller. Can anyone helps me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For button you have used input element with type **submit**, this will post the complete form. 
Try using button element which will not submit complete form.

```
<button type="button">
```

And your Controller action method to be called using jQuery Ajax.

Comment: that is not a problem ...how to pass datatable to the controller that is the issue

Comment: on click of generate button whole datatable display will sent to the controller